# Is there a General European English Accent?

Tags: english, accent, words, russian, italian

I have noticed my former trainer from Estonia, fellow students from Poland and Italy, even Khabib from UFC who comes from Dagestan speak with this accent.

[Here is a video of khabib from remote dagestan speaking with same accent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOV7DKQKI3s)

[Here is a video of  European Parliment leader who speaks with similar accent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNwgwysmLqA)

Answer (score 4):

Those people just happen to have accents that sound similar to your ears. Features common to several European languages but not your native English stand out to your ears.

It'd make sense to consider a General European English only if there were a conscious effort to teach it, or if Europeans were very unified culturally and developed it naturally.

That's not the case. Schools all over attempt to teach General American and/or Received British pronunciations, and most people just interact and are exposed to only their own local accents and native speakers' accents.

You may be interested in this, though: [International English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_english).